# Textarea not rendered for DataType.MultilineText

Tags: webforms, data-annotations, model-binding, asp.net-4.5, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have an EditItemTemplate within a ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms FormView. I've set an ItemType on the FormView so  I'm using DynamicControls to display and edit fields.

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ItemType="FooModel">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="message" DataField="Message" Mode="Edit" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

This seems to work ok until I set the DataType on my ItemType property to make it multiline, like so.

```
public class FooModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]      
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

This still gives me a standard text input. Any ideas?

I could work around it by using

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Message" Text='<%# Bind("Message") %>' runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

...but it would be nicer to just infer it from the data type on my property.

Thanks

Comment: Although if I work around it using an asp:textbox and Bind() then I loose my other data validation attributes which work fine, Required, StringLength etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit dynamic data field template. Everything that you need is to make a following check in `OnInit` of `Text_Edit.ascx` control:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    if(Column.DataTypeAttribute.DataType == DataType.MultilineText)
        TextBox1.TextMode =  TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
}
```

`Column` property of [FieldTemplateUserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.fieldtemplateusercontrol.aspx) gives you all the information about the model property metadata.

Comment: Should I have the DynamicData\FieldTemplate directory in my project already or do I need to add this and create the controls as necessary? I have an upgraded project rather than a new 4.5 project.

Comment: @JamesAntrobus I think you should have `DynamicData\FieldTemlates` folder in your project. Either copy it from new Dynamic Data project template or use NuGet package http://nuget.org/packages/DynamicDataTemplatesCS/.